# React-native Portal vs Modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am considering using React Portal concept to replace react-native Modal in some of my scenarios like Popover menu on click of card, dropdown etc.

I would like to understand **what are advantages and disadvantages of this approach**.
One thing I can notice is using portal is much faster compared to Modal.
Is there **anything else I should consider while using Portal over react-native Modals**?